# Cucumber Java - JUnit set monochrome over command line

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

What is the best way to disable color output for my Cucumber JUnit tests when they are run by a build machine?
It is possible to set `monochrome = true` in the `@CucumberOptions` annotation. The problem with that is, running the Tests locally should contain Color.

Setting `-Dcucumber.options.monochrome=true` is not working, for whatever reason.

Is there any way to set/override this from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution.
As stated here https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#list-configuration-options
Providing `-Dcucumber.ansi-colors.disabled=true` solves the issue.